# Hyperlinks in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I started working with LaTeX some months ago and this forum has been very useful for me.

Now I am writing a report and I want to have the ToC, LoF and LoT with hyperlinks. So I use the package:

```
\usepackage[dvips,breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

Then I compile via `\latex+dvips+ps2pdf+view pdf`. When the PDF is generated the link text does not break at end line (i.e., in ToC, LoF and LoT). [I also used `hypdvips` package](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=17716) but a lot of errors appear.

```
\usepackage{hypdvips}
```

Although [one solution](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-breaklinks) is to add `linktocpage`, I want to make the text active and not only the page number.

I also tried compiling via `latex+dvipdfm+view pdf` with the option `dvipdfmx` in `hyperref`

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}
```

This time the `breaklinks` problem is solved but the EPS figures are shifted.

I am using Texmaker 4.1, MiKTeX 2.9, Ghostscript 9.10 and GSview 5.0 on Windows 7.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: X-Post to [LaTeX-Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=24213&p=82312#p82308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following three packages:

```
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{hypdvips}
```

If you have `\bibliography` with `BibTeX` and you do not want a link page to go back from references, compile once with `\latex+dvips+ps2pdf` including:

```
\usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

and then compile once again but this time including `\usepackage{hypdvips}`

[image: Hyperlinks in ToC]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[a5paper,dvips]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[breaklinks,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{An extraordinary long title to show that titles are which are
linked in the toc are broken across lines}

foo \qquad
\url{An_extraordinary_long_title_to_show_that_titles_are_which_are_linked.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Herbert thank you for your reply. I also tried with `\usepackage{breakurl}` but 
it did not work. Very long titles are not well linked as short titles.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,dvips]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{An extraordinary long title to show that titles are which are
 linked in the toc are broken across lines}

\section{A short title}

 foo \qquad
 \url{An_extraordinary_long_title_to_show_that_titles_are_which_are_linked.pdf}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sure. that was the reason why I used option `colorlinks` for hyperref. Which, by the way. looks much better than the default rectangles

Comment: Instead of “answering” your own question, you should comment on Herbert's answer or edit the original question to include the additional information.